# Server returned an invalid soap fault when calling operation from class library

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services

I am using Visual Studio 2012. I have a ASP.NET MVC 4 web app that references a class library. This class library has a service reference. The service reference I added by inserting the URL to the .wsdl file.

I have set up everything correctly. When I do a call to one of the operations then I get an error:

> Server returned an invalid SOAP Fault.  Please see InnerException for more details.

Then when I view the inner exception:

> The data at the root level is invalid. Line 16, position 17.

I am doing everything right, I just don't know why I get this error when I do a call to one of the operations.  Where do I see what is returned? I have no control over this service, I am just consuming it.

Comment: Well, what data does the service return? Have you tried figuring out what exactly is wrong with the data?

Answer (score 0):

Run fiddler while making the request.  http://fiddler2.com/

This will allow you to see what is actually being sent and what is actually being returned